# I try to add SDL2 to my project but something is wrong

Tags: c++

I use `g++ -Isrc/include -Lsrc/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -LSDL2main -lSDL2` in cmd but it had an error:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64
mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function `main':
C:/_/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: `-LSDL2main` I think this should be `-lSDL2main` capital L sets the folder where lower case l links to a library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsdl%5D+undefined+reference+to+WinMain

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.